# iOS: Can HTMLReader load embedded images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-parsing

I'm developing an iOS news application that gets its contents from a url (JSON).

In the article's details ViewController i made a label to display the description, let's say i have the following string which the app will get from JSON object (form a url):

```
"bla bla bla <div>another bla bla bla</div><img src="some_image_src" />
bla bla blabla <strong>bla</strong>"
```

I'm using [HTMLReader](https://cocoapods.org/pods/HTMLReader) to remove the html tags and everything looks great except for the image in the string, how can i display the embedded images ?

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** HTMLReader documentation is very short and they didn't say anything about image tags

Answer (score 0):

Download image data with your url and use NSMutableAttributedString:

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:nil];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever"];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];
yourTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```